# How to calculate the average worker hashrate on a pool?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-profitability, asic

I just calculated the average hashrate of all poolminers on Slushpool by dividing the *Pool Scoring Hash Rate* by the amount of active workers:

So with current values that is: **641.1 Ph/s / 30287 ~= 21,2 TH/s**

Is this the right way to do it, or am I missing something? 
That seems to be pretty high ...

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted, if they answer your question and are complete enough, this way the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems correct, as far as I understand.

Comment: Ok, but why is the hashrate then so high?

Comment: Someone with several miners (say 10 antimner S9) could aggregate them and appear as a single user with (say 120 TH/s).

Comment: well, good point, but then it´s a misleading term used by Slushpool, to call it "Active Workers", because a worker normally is the entity of a single miner (like 10 Ant miner S9 = 10 workers even they are all owned by the same user)

Comment: @D.Hot I believe with Slushpool it is also possible to put several miners on the same worker.